# Is it possible to make an app to set an alarm using actions on google?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I want to make my own google assistant command that sets multiple alarms in one go. i.e. if I say "wake me up at 8 am without fail" it sets an alarm for 7:45, 7:50, 7:55, 8, and 8:05.

Is this even possible using Actions on Google? If so, would appreciate some guidance on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

The platform does not provide a way for third-party actions to set an alarm.